# Hausdorff spaces on dense set

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$ and let $h: A \rightarrow Y$ be continuous where $Y$ is Hausdorff. Prove that if $h$ may be extended to a continuous function $k:X \rightarrow Y$, then $k$ is uniquely determined by $h$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are continuous, then
$$\{x\in X\mid k_1(x) \not= k_2(x)\}$$
is open.

Comment: How do I use that $A$ is a dense set?

Comment: @Kumar leading question: what is the definition of dense - i.e. what does it mean for a set to be dense?